What is the Name of This Cross?
In the approbation given the 1854 edition of St. Alphonsus Liguori's Preparation for Death (or Considerations on the Eternal Maxims) one finds:

QUESTION: Does anyone know the name of this cross?
It seems neither to be an iron cross nor a maltese cross. I would like to know what it is called because I am hoping to reproduce it with LaTeX and make use of it in a current work of mine.
Thank you.

✠ U+2720 MALTESE CROSS is a Unicode character.

Many thanks. I had been wondering since Ray Butterworth's answer how I might also typeset a maltese cross which resembles the "cross paty or formy" found in https://www.theheraldrysociety.com/articles/crosses-paty-patonce-and-formy/ rather than say, using the \maltese command of LaTeX.


The term cross patonce in the 13th century indicated that the ends of the cross terminated in three prongs somewhat like a paw, and patonce was perhaps derived from patte=paw.
…
From the early eighteenth to the early twentieth century a cross with more or less widely splayed arms ending in three lobes, Fig. 1, was called a cross patonce
…

Fig. 1 Cross Patonce (a) after the arms of the Earl of Aumale in Westminster Abbey, 13th century. (b) after the seal of William de Vesci, c. 1230. (c) after the seal of William, Earl of Aumale c. 1240. (d) after the seal of William de Latimer 1301.
…
— Crosses Paty, Patonce and Formy | The Heraldry Society

Search: Cross Patonce, and select "Images" for many variations.

Many thanks for this helpful answer.

Yes, great answer, couldn't find it myself.

You may also have a look at the St Thomas Cross used by Roman Syrian Catholics and Orthodox Christians of Southern India. The Cross, believed to have been chiseled by Apostle Thomas has plenty of art in it. It stands on a pedestal that reminds one of lotus flower. All four ends have a shape of opening flower buds, attributing a special meaning that the Cross is a symbol of new and invigorated life. One can also see a dove representing the Holy Spirit hovering over the Cross. https://www.nasrani.net/amp/2008/02/29/analogical-review-on-st-thomas-cross-the-symbol-of-nasranis/

Thank you for posting this.

Welcome. Stay blessed.
